# How do I use Telethon string sessions to signin multiple accounts at the same time by readin them from Json file?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have this file that reads account data from Json file and logs me into a telethon session. I want a way to be able to register my Telegram client for all accounts in a file so that when I encounter a code like

```
 client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hi'))
```

He sends a text to all accounts as if I had registered each account separately and passed the command to him

json file

```
{
"accounts": [
        {
            "phone": "+88888888888",
            "api_id": 111111111,
            "api_hash": "fgse56...",
            "ter":"1dd..."

        }
    ]
}
```

init_session

```
with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.loads(f.read())

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)

accounts = config['accounts']

folder_session = 'session/'

for account in accounts:
    api_id = account['api_id']
    api_hash = account['api_hash']
    phone = account['phone']
    ter = account['ter']
    print(phone)

    client = TelegramClient(StringSession(ter), api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
    if client.is_user_authorized():
        print('Login success')
    else:
        print('Login fail')
    client.disconnect()
```

send massage

Finding a way to deal with several telethon sessions as if I were dealing with one client